# Token Comma Expected

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to add a parameter (Period) to change part of the SQL statement but I am getting the "Token Comma Expected" error:

```
 let
    Period = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Period"]}[Content]{0}[Period],
    Source = Sql.Database("FVC-HO-SQL-02", "FVCHLD", [Query="SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([NAMIBIA], 'SELECT *  FROM PAS19NFPM23.LedgerTransactions where GDC = ''D'' and PPeriod = "Period"')#(lf)union all#(lf)SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([NAMIBIA], 'SELECT *  FROM PAS19FREWB23.LedgerTransactions where GDC = ''D'' and PPeriod = Period')"])
```

[image: code]

Details above, unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever it used to say period=xxx use period="&Period&"